# winscard.dll not supported for UWP (System.TypeLoadException using pcsc-sharp library)

Tags: .net, uwp, dllimport, pcsc

I am trying to use v4 of **pcsc-sharp** library within a UWP application
https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp

I understand with v4, **pcsc-sharp** is now on .net standard 2.0 which UWP supports.

Good news is that we are able to Transmit CommandApdu and read public data of a ISO7816 smart card. The bad news is that this seems to work only in debug mode and when run in release mode, we get the following error:

> **Exception Details**
>
> {System.TypeLoadException: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'winscard.dll!SCardEstablishContext' from this method. Please look for this method in build warnings for more details.
>
> **Build warnings**
>
> Warning   MCG : warning MCG0007: Unresolved P/Invoke method 'winscard.dll!SCardSetAttrib' for method 'System.Int32 PCSC.Interop.Windows.WinSCardAPI.SCardSetAttrib(System.IntPtr, System.Int32, System.Byte[], System.Int32)'. Calling this method would throw exception at runtime.
>
> Please make sure the P/Invoke either points to a Windows API allowed in UWP applications, or a native DLL that is part of the package. If for some reason your P/Invoke does not satisfy those requirements, please use [DllImport(ExactSpelling=true) to indicate that you understand the implications of using non-UWP APIs.

How do you read into this ? Am I trying to do the impossible here ?

Incidentally, I have tried to enable .net native tool chain in debug mode. thats how I got these exception details. I also tried to run in both x64 and x86 modes but it aint working either way. it works in debug mode only when .net native toolchain is not checked in the project properties.

According to the error we have to do **DllImport** to call those methods, but in the code of **pcsc-sharp** we already have all those Dll import stuff on the methods we r trying to call. so it doesn't make sense why it is still giving us those errors.

Github issue : https://github.com/danm-de/pcsc-sharp/issues/70

Comment: The WACK utility is the better way to discover that your program is using components that are not permitted/supported in a UWP app.  But nice that the .NET Native compiler can tell you as well.  You have to do this the condoned way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/smart-cards

Comment: @HansPassant we already tried to use the pltform api for smart cards, but unfortunately we cant send apdu commands in them to get the public data. tht is why we had to use this external library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `WinScard.dll` is not currently supported for UWP. If there are features missing from the `SmartCard` API, you can send feedback via [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=smartcard) or the Feedback Hub.

Comment: so there is absolutely no way that we can use it with any enforcing like dllimport or anything like that?